# Why does the Swift compiler show each error 19 times?

Tags: swift

When running `swift build`, for some reason Swift will repeat the same error messages over a dozen times. When there are several (actual) errors, this makes the output very long and hard to parse. How do I fix this?

```
[redacted]:~/Dropbox/workspace/magnolia/Sources$ swift build
Building for debugging...
/home/luke/Dropbox/workspace/magnolia/Sources/Magnolia/Display/BaseGui.swift:1:19: error: ';' statements are not allowed
import Foundation;;
                  ^

/home/luke/Dropbox/workspace/magnolia/Sources/Magnolia/Display/BaseGui.swift:1:19: error: ';' statements are not allowed
import Foundation;;
                  ^

/home/luke/Dropbox/workspace/magnolia/Sources/Magnolia/Display/BaseGui.swift:1:19: error: ';' statements are not allowed
import Foundation;;
                  ^
... (this repeats 19 times)
```

(To be clear, the use of a semicolon error was just an example. I am not asking about that particular error!)

Comment: This is **not** Objective-C. Remove all semicolons. Probably you made 19 times the same mistake.

Comment: I agree, I can't think of any situation where it is right to use a semicolon in Swift other than to put two statements onto the same line.

Comment: The semicolons were just to show an error. My question is not about this particular error but the fact that it is repeated 19 times despite being a single line.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know much about the topic, but just by an accurate Google search, have you taken a look at this? It seems the same issue to me: https://github.com/apple/swift-driver/issues/1387#event-9645206631

Comment: Aha, that does seem to be the same issue, thanks. I had tried Googling but it didn't come up for me (maybe I needed to use the word "duplicate"?)

Answer (score 1):

The collocation `;<whitespace>;` is illegal in Swift. So the fix here is to delete the second semicolon. However, the first semicolon, while not itself illegal, is unnecessary, so I would advise omitting it too, as having it is considered bad style.

Comment: The reason you're getting the error multiple times might or might not have to do with the fact that your project is in a Dropbox shared folder. Do _not_ attempt to build a project from a Dropbox shared folder; bad things can happen. Also, I hope that this project is not also under Git control, as putting a Git repo in a Dropbox shared folder is also a really bad idea.

Comment: I know the semicolons are wrong. My question is not about this particular error, but the fact that it is repeated 19 times. Please actually read my question.

Comment: I'm with you 100% but since I can't reproduce that issue at my end, I can't help with it; I did make some suggestions in an earlier comment. Still, if you eliminate the errors, the error messages will repeat zero times, which does solve the problem after all.

Comment: Disabling dropbox doesn't seem to have an effect on error repetition.

Comment: @matt Would you mind editing your answer to include the Dropbox issue here? Because at the moment, the answer about syntax (from outside) does seem to be off-topic.

Comment: @Alex That would be rewriting history; Dropbox wasn't what I suggested, and in any case it didn't solve the problem according to the OP. If you want to "correct" what I said, simply submit your own answer under your own name.

Comment: @matt I asked you because I was supposed to moderate this answer since it seems to be not addressing OPs actual question, if I understand correctly. Instead of just deleting it I thought it was nicer to maybe focus on the dropbox issue since that seems to might have an actual cause.

Comment: But, as I said before, if you read the OP's comments the dropbox thing was irrelevant. So why would I want to lie about what I said in my answer? If you think the answer is wrong, downvote it or whatever. In my opinion the whole question should be deleted, since the OP has learned that it's a known issue with Swift itself. Either that or the OP should answer the question and accept the answer. It's the OP's fault that this has been left hanging.